# how to install Unite.vim in Vim?

Tags: vim, unite.vim

I want to use Vim to write scientific articles, and was hoping to use

Citation.vim for references management along with Zotero.

> https://github.com/vim-scripts/Citation.vim

To install Citation.vim, it is mentioned that Unite.vim has to be installed first.

> https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim

I am using the vim-plug plugin manager. I have cloned the files in my ~/.vim folder, but don't know how to install Unite.vim with the specific vim command.

> https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug

Does anyone has recommendations how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way,using in Vim, or writing in .vimrc:

```
Plug 'Shougo/unite.vim'
Plug 'vim-scripts/Citation.vim'
```